# Are odd shaped quads ok?

Tags: mesh, topology

Is this okay, wrong, what? I started 3d this year, and I didn't see anybody taking about this, but I think that later on when that mouth moves that vert will make the deform weird but I'm not 100% sure.

[image: face topology, with problem vertex marked]

Comment: sorry for bad english

Comment: It seems to be a mistake rather than something useful.  Suggestion, remove it for the time being.  I am assuming the popular aesthetic of smooth skin.  If you stated that you wanted a cut mark in the skin then that would be a different consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-rectangular quad is fine. (Most times it is the only way to keep a mesh all quads). Just be sure to keep them [convex quads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Simple_quadrilaterals).

**However**

There is almost* no need for the extra vertex and edge in there.
[image: modified topology]
You can still get all quads simply by removing that vertex and using the surrounding four vertices to make the face.

*There is always the issue of edge flow. This image below shows the edge flow of the two different methods. Do note that the method on the right is *much* less prone to pinching. 
[image: edge flow]